# Did Paul view a young widow's desire to remarry as an expression of wantonness against Christ? 1 Timothy 5:11

Tags: 1-timothy, context

> 1 Timothy:5.11  (NKJV)
>
> But refuse the younger widows; for **when they have
> begun to grow wanton against Christ**, they desire to marry

Does Paul view a young widow's desire for marriage as an expression of wantonness against Christ?

Please help me make sense of this phrase in the context in which it was used.

Comment: *Please help me make sense of **this verse**.* - Since verses and chapters were not originally part of the biblical books (in general) or of Paul's epistles (in particular), perhaps it would be best to understand the phrase in [context](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1_Timothy_5:9-15&interface=print&version=KJV).

Comment: @Lucian thanks Lucian. I've edited the question

Comment: @Lucian why the down vote Lucian.

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

My study of scripture reveals that marriage is an acceptable vocation, and I say vocation because married couples must work at maintaining a pure relationship. For instance "It is better to marry than to burn with passion" and "those who are married will have trouble in this world"...It all kind of boils down to how devoted and obedient you can be to Christ alone and his calling...God knows what we are made of and how we are made. As Jesus says in one passage " not all people can accept a celibate life style"...Paul also states that widows who have family should attempt to work with family to have their physical needs met, even if perhaps the other family members are non-believers. I think in any case he is giving a general guideline, having the Holy Spirit and knowing full well the nature of humanity...Also I might say that it is important to count the cost on any endeavor, including following Christ...Therefore have a sober appraisal of who you are and what you can do.

Comment: But I wonder who downvoted.